# react, creating a project issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am creating react app like following but i found an error.please guide me what is the error.

```
E:\React>create-react-app template-app

Creating a new React app in E:\React\template-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pha.24","dependencies'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muaaz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-24T11_52_18_657Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting template-app/ from E:\React
Done.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you take a look at the mentioned log file? The answer should be in there. And it's probably relevant to add to your post if you still don't know the solution after checking that log file.

Answer (score 0):

With this sort of thing, it's worth checking the issues on the relevant GitHub repo. From [issue #7261](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7261), it seems other people have run into this from time to time and running this fixes it for them:

```
npm cache clean --force
```